# Homography matrix in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I am creating an application where I'll find the bird view perspective of an image by multiplying it with a homography matrix. I have read a lot about it and it seems that the function to multiply the matrices is **warpPerspective()**. Although when I do so, the resulting image is an image where all pixels are zero and only the first row is not.

Please provide me with the way to multiply a homography matrix by an image whether is C++ or Python.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

tilt = np.pi * 35 / 180

a = np.zeros((3, 3))

a[0][0] = 1
a[1][1] = np.sin(tilt)
a[1][2] = -np.sin(tilt)
a[2][2] = np.cos(tilt)
a[2][2] = np.cos(tilt)

src = cv2.imread("S2.jpg")
width, height, depth = src.shape

output = cv2.warpPerspective(src, a, (width, height))

cv2.imwrite("results.png", output)
```

The image I'm applying the homography on:

[image: Source Image]

The result of using **warpPerspective** is:

[image: Result Image]

It can be seen that there is a small part on the top-left of resulting picture.

Your help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: can you please try a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 0
a[0][2] = 100
a[1][0] = 0
a[1][1] = 0
a[1][2] = 100
a[2][0] = 0
a[2][1] = 0
a[2][2] = 1 instead? your image should be moved 100 pixels to right and 100 to bottom. If that works, your homography is just wrong. (btw, you set the element [2][2] twice!)

Comment: looking at your code I guess you want to rotate the camera around some 3D axis? This doesnt work for a homography (since you want to rotate the camera and not the image)! You need 3D description of the scene and 4x4 transformation matrices, but that's not made for warpPerspective and image homographies. You have to compute the homography with an appropriate method.

Comment: I have tried the translation and it worked. Regarding the second comment, I am actually implementing this paper's work (https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~laganier/publications/topVI00.pdf) where the homography matrix is given in page 2 eq.6. If you have any equations or homography matrix parameters, that'll be highly appreciated if you provide it. Otherwise, please lead me to the direction that I should be taking.

Comment: did you describe the plane, calibrate the camera etc as named in the paper?

Comment: I didn't do that before, thanks for pointing it out. However, that doesn't do a difference. Please provide me with a way to implement this application even if it was C++. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry... no time and not enough experience to code that for your. Just calibrate your camera (`C matrix in the paper`) and give some approximation for `h` and the 2 angles and test the matrix of the paper again (and give the full matrix to your code, not just a part of it as you've done). If you are able to use matlab, maybe try it there first.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's got to do with your `a` matrix, since calling your code with

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1]],
             dtype=np.float32)
```

works fine.